# Struct Memory Allocation in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, struct

Does allocating a `struct` instance using `malloc` have any effect on the allocation of its members? Meaning that, is doing something like this:

```
typedef struct { int *i; } test;
int main() {
     test *t = malloc(sizeof(test));
     t->i = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

... is meaningless because `i` should be already on the heap, right ?

Or, the struct is just conceptual to help the programmer group two completely separate variables floating in memory? Meaning that: `test *t = malloc(sizeof(test))` just allocates the memory for storing pointers to the members on the heap?

I'm quite baffled about this ..

Comment: `t->i = malloc( sizeof(int) );` should give you a compiler warning that you are casting a pointer to an int. You do not need to allocate the memory for the `int` on the heap unless the struct was defined as `struct { int* i; }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466304/allocate-struct-and-memory-for-elements-in-one-malloc

Comment: @Klapsa2503: Oh yes, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a struct type "test", `malloc(sizeof(test))` allocates space for a complete struct, including all members and any padding between.  You are perhaps confused about the case where one or more of the members is a pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    char *string;
    char array[8];
} test;
```

In that case, the *pointer itself* is a member, and space is allocated for it, but the thing pointed to is *not* a member, and no space is allocated for that.

Contrast that with the case where the struct has an array member: the whole array is a member of the struct, and sufficient space is allocated in the struct for all its elements.

Comment: So if I have a struct that contains a pointer to a struct of some other kind, and I allocate it using `malloc`, then I'd have to use `malloc` again on the member struct so that it is allocated dynamically too, right ?

Comment: Yes, the `sizeof` the container struct (determining how much memory to allocate) includes space for the inner pointer, but not for a separate "inner" struct that could be pointed to.  If you don't want to point to an independent, pre-existing inner struct (as you might want in a linked list, for example) then you need to allocate memory separately for such an inner struct.

Answer (score 4):

The `i` field of `test` is a primitive `int`, and `malloc`ing `test` will take care of the memory needed by it. Assigning a result of `malloc` to `i` should produce a warning, as you're implicitly converting a pointer to an `int`.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, the question has been edited since the above answer was posted. If your `struct` contains a pointer, `malloc`ing the `struct` will allocate the memory to hold a pointer, but will **not** allocate the memory this pointer points to. For that, you'll need a second `malloc` call (e.g., `test->i = malloc (sizeof (int))`).

Comment: FYI this answer appears to be wrong due to edits to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You would only allocate the memory for i if i was a pointer to an int.  See this example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
        int i;
} test;

typedef struct
{
        int* i; 
} testp;

int main()
{
        test* foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
        foo->i = 3;

        testp* bar = malloc(sizeof(*bar));
        bar->i = malloc(sizeof(*bar->i));
        *bar->i = 3;
}
```

When you allocate the struct, there is already space allocated for the `int i`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the first malloc, there is enough memory to hold the whole structure, including the '*i', which has enough place to hold a pointer to an integer. The field *i however remains uninitialized! so you must not use *i before you assigned it with the second malloc that reserves memory for an integer.